# socket programming in c (segmentation core dump)

Tags: c, ftp, segmentation-fault

I'm really new to socket programming and I have been tinkering a little bit with the program and doing try and error. Im trying to send a txt file from client to server but keep encountering segmentation core dump. I have tried everything and hit a wall and was wondering where did i go wrong. Pardon if its a bit messy, ive been doing it with my partner and we've been testing out different stuffs. It only happens on the client side when it chooses "send".

Client

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<netdb.h>
#include<sys/ioctl.h>
#define FNAME file1
#define BUFSIZE 128
#define SIZE 1024
#define PORT 20

int checkIfFileExists(const char *filename);
void write_file(int sockfd);
void send_file(FILE *fp, int sockfd);


int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    //declaration
    int socket_desc;//sockfd
    struct sockaddr_in server; //sockaddr_in server_addr
    FILE *fp;
    char command[50];
    char *filename;
    int new_sock;
    char *fname;
    char rbuff[1024];
    char sendbuffer[100];
    int sfd =0, n=0, b;
    


    //Create socket
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
    if (socket_desc == -1)
    {
        puts("Could not create socket");
    }
    else 
    {
        puts("socket created\n");
    }
    
    memset(rbuff, '0', sizeof(rbuff));
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.56.4"); //Please enter the ip address of your Server VM
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons( PORT );

    //Connect to remote server
    if (connect(socket_desc , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        puts("connect error");
        return 1;
    }

    puts("Connected \n");


    
    

    printf("Enter FTP command: ");
    scanf("%s",command);
    send(socket_desc,command,sizeof(command),0);
    
if(strcmp(command, "send") == 0)
{

   /* send_file(fp, socket_desc); 
    printf("[+]File data sent successfully.\n"); */
    
    fopen("new.txt", "rb");
    if(fp != NULL)
    {
        
        while( (b = fread(sendbuffer, 1, sizeof(sendbuffer), fp))>0 )
        {
        
        return 2;
        }
        send(sfd, sendbuffer, b, 0);
        perror("File");
    }

     fclose(fp);
 }

   
    


else if(strcmp(command, "check") == 0)

{
     if(checkIfFileExists("new.txt"))
    {
        printf("file exists");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("file does not exists");
    }

}

else if(strcmp(command, "create") == 0)
    
{
    write_file(new_sock);
    printf("[+]Data written in the file successfully.\n");

}



    printf("[+]Closing the connection.\n");
    close(socket_desc);
    return 0;
    

}


int checkIfFileExists(const char* filename)
{
    struct stat buffer;
    int exist = stat(filename,&buffer);
    if(exist == 0)
        return 1;
    else  
        return 0;
}

void write_file(int sockfd){
  int n;
  FILE *fp;
  char *filename = "new.txt";
  char buffer[SIZE];

  fp = fopen(filename, "w");
  while (1) {
    n = recv(sockfd, buffer, SIZE, 0);
    if (n <= 0){
      break;
      return;
    }
    fprintf(fp, "%s", buffer);
    bzero(buffer, SIZE);
  }
  return;
}

void send_file(FILE *fp, int sockfd){
  int n;
  char data[SIZE] = {0};

  while(fgets(data, SIZE, fp) != NULL) {
    if (send(sockfd, data, sizeof(data), 0) == -1) {
      perror("[-]Error in sending file.");
      exit(1);
    }
    bzero(data, SIZE);
  }
}
```

Server

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>   //inet_addr
#include<string.h> // starlen
#include<unistd.h> // write
#include<net/if_arp.h>
#include<sys/ioctl.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#define PORT 20
#define SIZE 1024


void receive_file(int sock_desc);
void write_file(int sockfd);


int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    //declaration
    int socket_desc, new_socket , new_sock;
    struct sockaddr_in server, new_addr; 
    socklen_t addr_size;
    char buffer[SIZE];
    char fname[50];
    FILE *fp;
    int fd =0, confd = 0,b,tot;
    char buff[1025];
    int num;
    
    /*int sockfd, new_sock;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr, new_addr;
    socklen_t addr_size;
    char buffer[SIZE];*/
    
    //Create socket
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
    if (socket_desc == -1)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket");
    }
        
    memset(&new_addr, '0', sizeof(new_addr));
    memset(buff, '0', sizeof(buff));
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; //Please enter the ip address of your Server VM
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons( PORT );


    if( bind(socket_desc,(struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        //puts("bind failed. Error");
        printf("Error binding socket to port %d.\n", PORT);
        return 1;
    }
    puts("Binding successfull.");

    
    
    //Listen
    listen(socket_desc , 3);


    if (new_socket<0)
    {
        perror("accept failed");
        return 1;
    }

    addr_size = sizeof(new_addr);
    new_sock = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr*)&new_addr, &addr_size);
    
     while(1){
        confd = accept(fd, (struct sockaddr*)NULL, NULL);
        if (confd==-1) {
            perror("Accept");
            continue;
        }
        FILE* fp = fopen( "new.txt", "wb");
        tot=0;
        if(fp != NULL)
        {
            while( (b = recv(confd, buff, 1024,0))> 0 ) 
            {
                tot+=b;
                fwrite(buff, 1, b, fp);
            }

            printf("Received byte: %d\n",tot);
            if (b<0)
               perror("Receiving");

            fclose(fp);
        } 
        
        else 
        {
            perror("File");
        }
        close(confd);
    }
    
    write_file(new_sock);
    printf("[+]Data written in the file successfully.\n");
    
    receive_file(new_sock);
    printf ("the file has been transferred");


    close(socket_desc);
    return 0;
    
}

void write_file(int sockfd){
  int n;
  FILE *fp;
  char *filename = "receive.txt";
  char buffer[SIZE];

  fp = fopen(filename, "a");
  while (1) {
    n = recv(sockfd, buffer, SIZE, 0);
    if (n <= 0){
      break;
      return;
    }
    fprintf(fp, "%s", buffer);
    bzero(buffer, SIZE);
  }
  return;
}

void receive_file(int sock_desc){
  int n;
  FILE *fp;
  char buffer[SIZE];
  char *filename;
  fp = fopen(filename, "w");
  while (1) {
    n = recv(sock_desc, buffer, SIZE, 0);
    if (n <= 0){
      break;
      return;
    }
    fprintf(fp, "%s", buffer);
    bzero(buffer, SIZE);
  }
  return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to *think* about what your code does.

The client has an obvious bug (probably first of many). You have:

```
FILE *fp;  // uninitialized pointer
...
if(strcmp(command, "send") == 0)
{    
    fopen("new.txt", "rb");  // What does this do?
    if(fp != NULL)           // Compare uninitialized pointer with NULL.
```

Pretty obvious that you mean to *assign* the result of `fopen` to `fp`.

Please read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).